# Call http url (php) generates always WebException

Tags: c#, php, http, webrequest

I can call the following url in a browser and it works:

http://test.shop.ch/shop/Admin/caller/caller_aufruf.php?do=set_kategorien

It does not give soemthing back - only execute the php.

But when I try to call the same with C# like

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    var uri = new Uri("http://test.shop.ch/shop/Admin/caller/caller_aufruf.php?do=set_kategorien");
    cResponse = client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

I always get a WebException:

The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Can someone help me, what I am doing wrong? - Thanks.

Comment: The issue is the `401 Unauthorized`, it expects there to be headers sent for basic authentication and you fail to supply them.

Comment: A wild guess would be that the server authorizes only for standard browsers. May be you need to try and replicate the exact request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code 401 that you are getting is indicating that [you do not have permissions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#401)
Which means that before you can call `setcategory` you need to obtain a token (or cookie) by calling login page, or send it in headers or whatever mechanism of authentication is used on your shop site and only then you can call `setcategory`.